# Set Image,from NSDictionary,iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I have image path in a  NSDictionary which is like( with key: image_path)

> [productDictionary objectForKey:@"image_path"];

i am able to set the text on a label from Same dictionary
like

> cell.lbl.text = [productDictionary objectForKey:@"somestatus"];

but have no idea,how to do the same for image (to set on an UIImageview).

how can i set it on UIImageview?
instead of this:

> cell.imgvQuotes.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"static.png"];

i want to set image from the dictionary instead of  "static.png"

I have  a URL of image after parsing,which is like

http://google.com/images/noimage.png  //won't work ,just an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
id imageName = [productDictionary objectForKey:@"image_path"];
cell.imgvQuotes.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use same method but instead take image name from dictionary as follows:

```
cell.imgvQuotes.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[productDictionary objectForKey:@"image_path"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Dictionary contains image names instead of imagePath the above answer by @Adil is correct.

If the dictionary contains the path as you mentioned in the question (URL)

> cell.imgvQuotes.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[productDictionary objectForKey:@"image_path"]];